# How to populate FolderName to Metadata (either EnterpriseKeywords or Hierarchical)

Tags: workflow, folder, taxonomy

How could I possibly bind my Folder structure to some sort of metadata. That is, I am looking for a way to populate Information given to my folder in a library (Name and ideally hierarchical structure) to the managed metadata column (could be Enterprise Keywords).

In that way I would like to keep the well known structure of folders but most important be able to find docs easily.

Is there somebody out there knowing an easy way to get things done, perhaps via workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://channel9.msdn.com has a demo for you with explanations from a Microsoft Premier Field Engineer Lori Gowin: [Content Types, Metadata and You](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC226).

In a nutshell, a Default Column Values setting in Document Library settings appears exactly for that when you activate the `Metadata Navigation and Filtering, was it?` feature. Also take a look at this blog that describes it: [Folders vs Metadata](http://www.sharepointsharon.com/2014/02/folders-vs-metadata/).

If you want to develop something more sophisticated, refer to [Location-Based Metadata Defaults in SharePoint Server 2010 (ECM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557925(v=office.14).aspx) on MSDN.